# Vue js task if statement

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

**Hello**, I have a little task in vue js and have a little problem, I need If statement which makes ul border color green if price < 140. I need help, thank you.I tried some ways but didn't work.
See the code below:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Vue</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
ul{
    border:2px solid black;
    width:450px;
}
#app{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
#card{
    margin-left:5px;
}

</style>
<body>

<div id = "app" >
<div id ="card" v-for="post in posts" > 
    
   <ul>
    <img :src="post.img" :value="post.id">
        <li>{{post.title}}</li>
        <li>{{post.price}}</li>
        <li>{{post.date}}</li>
   </ul>
</div>
</div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
var card = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        posts: [
            { id: 1, title: 'Cat', price: 145, date: "1 year ago", img: 'https://www.pngonly.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Cat-Clipart-PNG-Image.png' },
            { id: 2, title: 'Cat2', price: 80, date: "2 years ago", img: 'https://www.pngonly.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Cat-Clipart-PNG-Image.png' },
            { id: 3, title: 'Cat3', price: 180, date: "3 years ago", img: 'https://www.pngonly.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/Cat-Clipart-PNG-Image.png' }
        ],
        baseStyles: {
            borderColor:'green',
        },
    }
})
```

Solved

Comment: The Vue documentation at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html should help you [How to add\remove classes dynamically based on variables to show your border].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it with the ternary operator

```
   <ul :style="{ 'border-color': post.price < 140 ? 'green' : '' }">
      <img :src="post.img" :value="post.id">
      <li>{{post.title}}</li>
      <li>{{post.price}}</li>
      <li>{{post.date}}</li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: @WuLo i suggest to install the extension "Vetur" on your editor if oyu dont have it